# apache2 VirtualHost subdomain configuration not working

Tags: apache, subdomain

All i want is, that www.example.com redirects to example.com, that works, but i can't add another VirtualHost which would allow admin.example.com for admins.

Here are my .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias old.website.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/redirect
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName admin.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/admin
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

However, if i enter admin.example.com i get redirected to example.com and if i use anything else as subdomain, for example test.example.com or anything.example.com the normal example.com site is shown BUT in the URL field you can still see the original URL (anything.example.com, ...) which isn't the case when using admin.example.com. My .htaccess file in the /var/www/redirect directory looks like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

Comment: Make sure you restart apache after you change your server configuration.
Also to debug more put some errors in your second virtual host.
Then try that if that reaches if yes it can be debugged later.

Comment: Is there a `.htaccess` in `/var/www/admin`?

Comment: @Chand Pakash if i add an error in i get this when reloding apache: "Job for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details."

Comment: @Dusan Bajic no there isn't a .htaccess in /var/ww/admin

Comment: @ZockerAxel did you get thing binded with port 80?

Comment: @Chand Prakash what?

Comment: Try these these two commands:-
1. (netstat -ta | grep ':http') | grep 'LISTEN'
2. (netstat -ta | grep ':80') | grep 'LISTEN'

This will list the process if that exits. If that does not show anything that means process has not been started....

Comment: @Chand ok, command "(netstat -ta | grep '.http') | grep 'LISTEN'" returns "tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:https              [::]:*                  LISTEN" and command "(netstat -ta | grep '.80) | grep 'LISTEN'" won't return anything

Comment: What I can see here is nothing is working on port 80. 
Check the status of apache and check which port it is binded to.

Comment: @Chand my server is working with the port 80 and 443 (as example.com is SSL-secured and www.example.com and every other subdomain are currently NOT)

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seemed to be a google-chrome only error that was caused by my browser data, if anybody else is having problems with it, try using Icognito Mode in Chrome, it should work there.

Thanks to Chand Prakash for helping me